# Why no neutral wire on Double-Pole Single Outlet?

Tags: electrical, garage

I am doing some basic wiring in my garage. Basically extending a 220V circuit plug to another part of the garage. When I opened up the box to look inside, I noticed something unfamiliar to me.

There does not seem to be a neutral wire, only 2 hots and a ground.

For example Home Depot sells this [220V plug](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-Commercial-Grade-Double-Pole-Single-Outlet-White-R52-05821-0WS/100356999?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla=&mtc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D27-027_002_WIRING_DEVIC-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-4035595-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PL3&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D27-027_002_WIRING_DEVIC-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-4035595-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PL3-71700000112195205--&gad_source=1&gclsrc=ds), which is exactly what I'm looking at extending.

Notice there are screws for 2 hots and a ground.

So what happened to the neutral? And how does the electricy complete the circuit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [a Technology Connections video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4) for your question.

Our setup is 240V with a neutral in the middle, so if you want 120V you take it hot-neutral, and if you want 240V you take it hot-hot.  Many loads including EVs (which that circuit is fantastic for, by the way) only need 240V and do not have any onboard 120V loads, so they don't need neutral.

Contrast with a dryer, where any given model is made in 2 variants: a 120V plug-in one with a gas heat stove to make the hot air; and a 120V plug-in one with a giant 240V toaster coil to make the hot air.  So while it needs 240V for the heater, it also needs 120V and that's why it needs 4 prongs.  (well there's a legacy 3-prong socket with no ground that predates the 1965 grounding requirements, and was for some reason allowed to continue up til 1996).

The electricity is completing the circuit from hot to hot.  Philippine houses are wired similar to ours but they are not given neutral. All loads are hot-hot.